# OpenGL Terrain Texture3D Map

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping, terrain

In OpenGL I am trying to map a **terrain** with 8 512x512 images using **texture3D** to get blended texture change.
But OpenGL forces me to allocate 512x512x512 array instead of 512x512x8
What can be solution

Comment: *"But OpenGL forces me to allocate 512x512x512 array instead of 512x512x8 What can be solution"* - Does it really? How did you come to this conclusion? Because as long as you use an OpenGL version of 2.0+ (and thus an implementation that is no more than 10 years old), you can use arbitrary texture sizes (and aspect ratios).

Comment: @ChristianRau: 3D textures were never required to be cubes. You could *always* use 512x512x8 (assuming the max 3D texture size allowed 512 at all)..

Comment: @NicolBolas Interresting, and I thought it was NPOT that allowed for rectangular sizes, but I guess then only for 2D textures. And what about a 512x8x512 texture then (stupid question, but maybe the 2D sub-part is treated specially?)?

Comment: @ChristianRau: Rectangular textures have always been allowed. Now granted, some earlier APIs (GLIDE, I think) didn't allow rectangular textures. But OpenGL has always had them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But Opengl forces me to allocate 512x512x512

What gave you that idea? 512×512×8 is a completely valid 3D texture size. For terrains you might also look at GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, which is initialized with glTexImage3D as well, but doesn't interpolate between the layers, which is usefull in certain situations.

Comment: But I need interpolation to blend one texture to another

Comment: @user2362969: Then just use GL_TEXTURE_3D, you can use that format you want to use just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you need interpolation to blend one texture into another, you should also try using a GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY and just manually blend the textures together in the fragment shader.
Although it might seem that it's better to take advantage of the automatic hardware magnification filter, bear in mind that for GL_TEXTURE_3D implementation it's far more likely that the neighboring pixels in 6 directions will get cached, and from what I understand you have more emphasis on the individual 2D textures in the set and their neighboring layers, so you're better off having the hardware make 3 cache lines, each in 4 directions.
It's a good idea to try both and see what performs better